# Google Analytics - Tracking different links that point to same URL

Tags: google-analytics

If I have 3 links on a page that point to the same URL, Google Analytics doesn't seem to differentiate between them.  It will tell me the overall percentage of clicks to that URL but not the percentages unique to each of the links.

How do I get GA to tell me which links are most clicked even though they share the same URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best bet is to use [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide), with a different label on link to tell them apart.

One gotcha -- `_trackEvent` works by requesting a tracking pixel from Google. If you leave the page before the request has had a chance to complete, the event may not be recorded. The following code works by delaying the link by a small amount (150 ms) if the link doesn't open in a new window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackIt(link, label) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link', link.href, label]);
    if (link.target == '_blank') return true
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 150);
    return false;
}
</script>
<a href="someURL" onclick="return trackIt(this, 'label1');">link 1</a>
<a href="someURL" onclick="return trackIt(this, 'label2');">link 2</a>
```

Comment: This won't help with in-site Analytics feature. That's probably what OP s looking for.

Comment: `_trackEvent` has a built-in delay to ensure it gets tracked, so no need to wrap it in a function with a timeout.

Comment: @CrayonViolent -- have you got any references for `_trackEvent` having a built in delay? I haven't seen anything in any Google docs, but have seen reference to using setTimeout.

Comment: @mike: I don't have a link for you..it's just what I see happening in ga.js

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question may have changed since it was asked, and since this post appears high in search results, I'd be remiss if I didn't offer this answer.

Analytics has a feature called **[Enhanced Link Attribution](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en)**, which separates out tracking statistics for links on a page which have the same destination. This solves the exact issue for this question.

The documentation linked above is clear, but in short:

- Turn on the *Use enhanced link attribution* feature in your property's admin settings
- Add `id` attributes to your links to distinguish them from one another
- Add the following line to your tracking code:

  - `ga('require', 'linkid');`

Note that, according to the article, enabling this feature may cause some slowdown in report generation and there are some nuances to the data, but it can be disabled at any time.